# How can I remove characters from @fname in batch script when outputting to another file

Tags: batch

I am VERY new to batch scripting, but here is what I have been able to come up with from running several searches.

```
@ECHO OFF

pushd %~dp0
FORFILES /m *_graphic.txt /c "CMD /C type Graphic_Header.txt , @file > Graphic_@fname.DLB"  ***------------> I need the @fname minus the last 8 characters***
FORFILES /m *_dpl.txt   /c "CMD /C type Label_Header.txt , @file > Label_@fname.DLB" -------------------> ***I need the @fname minus the last 4 characters***

PAUSE
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: It’s generally a good idea to say what you want to do in a plain English sentence in the text/body of your question. Hiding it in comments in the code is not such a good idea, especially when readers need to scroll to bring those comments into view. It would also be nice to say at least a little about what your batch file is doing, overall.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to an IT friend of mine and he recommended that I just do a simple PowerShell script to rename the files.  Below is the coding for it:

```
get-childitem *_graphic.dlb | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_graphic", "") }
get-childitem *_dpl.dlb | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_dpl", "") }
```